# Marshmallow_MongoEngine: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'marshmallow.compat'

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, marshmallow

I'm using MongoDB with MongoEngine, and am trying to serialize/deserialize with Marshmallow_MongoEngine.

My code is as follows:

```
import marshmallow_mongoengine as ma

from models.profile import Profile

class ProfileSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

The error I get is:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'marshmallow.compat'`

And a partial trackback is:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from marshmallow_mongoengine.schema import (
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow_mongoengine/schema.py", line 6, in <module>
    from marshmallow.compat import with_metaclass
```

It seems like the error is a result of with_metaclass being called which as I understand was originally in Marshmallow for backwards compatibility with Python 2.x and is no longer being used. Is there a solution to this? Or another way to serialize/deserialize data to and from the DB?

P.S.
I have tried using json_util.dumps, but it returns my values in this format: [\"_id\", \"name\"] rather than a nice output that I'm used to getting from something like marshmallow-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

marshmallow-mongoengine is not compatible with marshmallow 3.

There has been work on this but it has not been merged (yet ?): https://github.com/MongoEngine/marshmallow-mongoengine/pull/11.

BTW, the author of marshmallow-mongoengine wrote a marshmallow-based ODM, [umongo](https://github.com/Scille/umongo/), that is meant to do the same as mongoengine + marshmallow-mongoengine.

Your options are:

- help porting marshmallow-mongoengine to marshmallow 3 or move to umongo (good)
- stick to marshmallow 2 (bad)
- use the branch in marshmallow 3 compatiblity PR above in your code (ugly)

Comment: I forgot to mention that umongo + mashmallow 3 is still beta. I'm working on it. I hope to release a stable 3.0 release soonish.